# Unable to Establish WebSocket Connection Using Django Channels

Tags: websocket, django-channels

I am attempting to create a real-time net worth tracker using Django for the backend and JavaScript for the frontend. I am using Django Channels to implement WebSockets.

The problem is that my web socket fails to establish an initial connection.

Here's my routing.py: it's on the app level

**routing.py**

```
# routing.py
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/networth/', consumers.NetWorthConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

on the javascript side, I'm attempting to to connect with (note I've also tried hardcoding)
**stacking.js**

```
window.socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/networth/')
// window.socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/networth/');
```

**error**
the error I'm getting is: [Error] WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/networth/' failed: There was a bad response from the server.

**addtitional context**
I've tried adding logging to my server side. The logs I setup do not appear in the server logs which I believe means that it never reaches my consumers. I've doubled checked my asgi.py, consumer.py, settings and routing.py. They seem correct. Here they are if it helps.

**asgi.py**

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

from stackingcommas.routing import ws_urlpatterns

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'wealth.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import stackingcommas.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(     
    {         
        "http": django_asgi_app,         
        # "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(             
        #   AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(ws_urlpatterns))         
        # ),     
        "websocket": URLRouter(ws_urlpatterns),
    } 
)
```

**consumers.py**

```
import json
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class NetworthConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        logger.info("WebSocket is connecting...")  # <-- Log message for connection
        # Create a group with the name 'networth'
        self.group_name = 'networth'
        
        # Add the socket to the group
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket is disconnecting. Close code: {close_code}")  # <-- Log message for disconnection
        # Remove the socket from the group upon disconnection
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        logger.info(f"Received text_data: {text_data}")  # <-- Log message for received data
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        net_worth = text_data_json['net_worth']
        
        # Send the message to the group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send_networth',
                'net_worth': net_worth
            }
        )

    # Custom handler for the 'send_networth' type of message
    async def send_networth(self, event):
        net_worth = event['net_worth']
        logger.info(f"Sending net_worth: {net_worth}")  # <-- Log message for sending data
        
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'net_worth': net_worth
        }))
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for wealth project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-0toh(g%kz6rlj@$s))@^f1a0*+%os=s%7)9oj=@1jp0%@$n9c%'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'stackingcommas',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels',
    # 'celery',
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
]

# CELERY_BROKER_URL = '/Users/baronjon/Desktop/coding/wealth/db.sqlite3'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wealth.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wealth.wsgi.application'

ASGI_APPLICATION = "wealth.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Los_Angeles'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

# STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  # Change 'staticfiles' to the desired directory name


# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'stackingcommas.CustomUser'

# Celery configurations
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'pyamqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//'  # Change to your RabbitMQ broker URL
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
``'

the only thing that appears in my server logs are a series of ws connects and ws disconnects 
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/networth/ [127.0.0.1:58338]
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/networth/ [127.0.0.1:58341]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/networth/ [127.0.0.1:58346]
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/networth/ [127.0.0.1:58347]



- I've tried adding loggers to my consumers.py to see where the issue may be. But my loggers are not appearing which makes me believe that the web socket connection is not reaching the consumers

- I've checked my asgi.py, settings.py, routing.py, and consumers.py settings.

- I've tried to use both python3 manage.py runserver and daphne wealth.asgi:application

- I've temporarily set allowed hosts to ['*']

- I've confirmed with redis-cli that my redis server is running
```